# A weird thing in c# Encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

I convert a `byte array` to a `string` , and I convert this `string` to `byte array`. 
these two byte arrays are different.

As below:

```
byte[] tmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b));
```

Suppose b is a byte array.

> b[0]=3, b[1]=188, b[2]=2 //decimal system

Result:

> tmp[0]=3, tmp[1]=63, tmp[2]=2

So that's my problem, what's wrong with it?

Comment: ASCII only has 7bits of data. You are looking for ANSI or some other encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII is 7-bit only, so others are invalid. [By default it uses `?` to replace any invalid bytes and that's why you get a `?`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#FallbackStrategy)

For 8-bit character sets, you should be looking for either the **[Extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)** (which is later defined "ISO 8859-1") or the **[code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)** (which is often *confused* with Extended ASCII, but in fact it's not).

You can use the following code:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
// For CP437, use Encoding.GetEncoding(437)
byte[] tmp = enc.GetBytes(enc.GetString(b));
```

Answer (score 5):

188 is out of range for ASCII. Characters that are not in the corresponding character set are transposed to '?' by design (would you prefer transposing to "1/4"?)

Answer (score 1):

The character `188` is not defined for ASCII. Instead, you're getting `63`, which is a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

The [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set has a range from 1 to 127. You can see 188 is not in this range and is converted to ? (= ASC 63).

Answer (score 1):

Not every sequence of bytes is necessarily a valid sequence of encoded values for a particular encoding.

So the result of `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b)` on an *arbitrary* array of bytes, `b`, is poorly defined. (And could be, for any other encoding also).

If you need to take an *arbitrary* byte array and obtain a sequence of characters, you might want to look into the `Convert` classes [`ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) and [`FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx). If that's not what you're trying to do, maybe explain the original *problem* to us.

Answer (score 0):

`188` isn't in the range of ASCII (7 bit), you should use [`Encoding.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) to get the ANSI encoding:

```
byte[] b = new byte[3]{ 3, 188, 2 };
byte[] tmp = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Encoding.Default.GetString(b));
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `Encoding.Default`, as the resulting `Encoding` depends on the settings of the machine one is using and can therefore change. Better to use `Encoding.GetEncoding(codePage)` and provide the exact codepage.